# PySerial ValueError: unexpected keyword arguments: {'debug_output': <RootLogger root (DEBUG)>}

Tags: python, logging, pyserial

I got an arduino talking to my python program over pyserial. In rare instances the serial communication does not work so I though of writing all the communication to a log.
so I added a logging instance:

```
import logging
debuglog=logging.getLogger()
debuglog.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.FileHandler("logfilePRC_serial_"+datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S")+".log")
debuglog.addHandler(fh)
```

and added the debuglog to the pyserial command:

```
self.prc = serial.Serial (port=port, baudrate =38400 , bytesize=8, writeTimeout = 0, timeout=0,
            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits= serial.STOPBITS_ONE , debug_output = debuglog)
```

now I get the following error message: ValueError: unexpected keyword arguments: {'debug_output': <RootLogger root (DEBUG)>}
I have no clue what exactly is expected the docummentation(https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html) says a logging.Logger object sould be put there. That is what I thought I did.

Comment: Which version of pyserial are you on? And which log message specifically do you expect the logger to handle?

Answer (score 2):

`serial.Serial` does not have that attribute. See the [`__init__`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.__init__) docs:

```
 def __init__(port=None, baudrate=9600, bytesize=EIGHTBITS, parity=PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=None,xonxoff=False, rtscts=False,
    write_timeout=None, dsrdtr=False, inter_byte_timeout=None, exclusive=None):
```

Based on https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html, it seems to only be in [`rfc2217.PortManager`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.rfc2217.PortManager):

```
def __init__(serial_port, connection, debug_output=False):
```

For logging serial communication, you could simply do something like:

```py
data = self.prc.read_until().strip()
debuglog.debug(f"Received data: {data}")
```

Naturally, you can replace `read_until` with your function of choice, as well as log errors (e.g. `SerialException`) or other information you may want to debug.

Does this help?